# babel.transform() function not using .babelrc or package.json config

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am trying to use Babel to transform ES6 to ES5 that is already loaded into a variable. However, I am finding contrary to the Babel documentation **`babel.transform()`** is not using the configuration files to transform the code.

**The following demonstrates my issue:**

**package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "babel-test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            ["env", {
                "targets": {
                    "ie": 8
                }
            }]
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
    }
}
```

**test.js:**

```
const a = 0
```

**index.js:**

```
const babel = require('babel-core')
console.log(babel.transform('const a = 0').code)
console.log(babel.transformFileSync('test.js').code)
```

**CLI:**

```
$ node index.js
const a = 0;
"use strict";

var a = 0;
```

As you can see **`babel.transformFileSync()`** is using the config and **`babel.transform()`** isn't.

How do I get **`babel.transform()`** to use the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.babelrc` files are searched for relative to the file being compiled, so if it doesn't know the name of the file, it can't find it.

```
babel.transform('const a = 0', {filename: "test.js"}).code)
```

for instance will work.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks. I think that should be in their documentation.